# Math rounding method

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I'm trying to find some `Math` using for such rounding, if it is  exist as method:

```
3219 to 3300
11380 to 11400
12583 to 12600
8275 to 8300
1778 to 1800
399 to 400
340 to 400
305 to 400
266 to 300
123 to 200
32 to 100
3 to 100
1 to 100
```

Comment: So you want to round up to the closest 100?

Comment: Divide by 100, make rounding, multiply by 100.

Comment: divide by 100, add 0.5, round, multiply by 100

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: based on the last lines, I think the OP wants to round **up** (so ceiling).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Apparently people don't have to think for themselves anymore...

Comment: @nikorio: What should `-53` round to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example, you want to **round up to the closest 100**, you can do this with:

```
int x = 3219; // or any other input
int result = (x+99)/100*100;
```

The advantage of this algorithm is that you *stay in the integer world*. So that means that there are no rounding errors (and as long as the subresult can be represented as an integer), we are fine.

You can **generalize** this method like:

```
public static int RoundUp(this int x, int n = 100) {
    return (x+n-1)/n*n;
}
```

Where `n` is the number to which you want to round up.

Based on [@wenston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360211/weston)s answer, you can construct a *branchfree* algorithm that suffers less from integer overflow:

```
public static int RoundUp(this int x, int n = 100) {
    int r = x % n;
    return x + (n - r) % n;
}
```

Comment: You can make this an extension method.

Comment: @KfirGuy: that's a great idea. Done.

Comment: Suffers from integer overflow e.g. `2147483000 != RoundUp(2147482999, 1000)`

Comment: @weston: which was mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Yes, the subresult, it says that now.

Comment: @weston: and there is also a branchfree variant of your algorithm.

Comment: Cool, good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var value = 1234;
var result = (int)(Math.Ceiling(value/100f)*100);
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent integer overflow issues with intermediate results (e.g. `RoundUp(2147482999, 1000)`) we should not add `n` to `x` before the divide:

```
public static int RoundUp(int x, int n) {
    var r = x % n;
    if (r == 0) return x;
    return x + n - r;
}
```

`x % n` is the remainder of a divide. If this is non-zero, we need to add the compliment of this (`n - x % n`) which is in the range `[1..n]`. When it is `== n`, we actually want it to add zero, so we can achieve this by another `% n` as [Willem pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43261963/360211), which makes it branchless but with two mods instead of one.

```
public static int RoundUp(int x, int n) {
    return x + (n - x % n) % n;
}
```

And, just a reminder, if you really care about integer overflow beyond this, then you can wrap in a `checked` block:

```
public static int RoundUp(int x, int n) {
    checked
    {
        return x + (n - x % n) % n;
    }
}
```